# webservices, where can find a free web service for Currency convert?

Tags: web-services

as topic, 
  I have googing, but still no good result .

thanks for your help.

Regards

Comment: http://www.ecb.int/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html 

I think this is what I want , thanks all :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this is free http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx

Answer (score 0):

It isn't free, but i've used xe.com.  It is relatively inexpensive and easy to implement.